# Is there a benefit for a List<? extends MyObject>?

Tags: java, generics, extends

Given a simple class …

```
public class Parent {

    private final String value;

    public Parent(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

… and a subclass of it, …

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child(String value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

… the following program compiles and executes without errors or warnings:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<? extends Parent> items = getItems();
        for (Parent p : items) {
            System.out.println(p.toString());
        }
    }

    private static List<? extends Parent> getItems() {
        List<Parent> il = new ArrayList<Parent>();
        il.add(new Parent("Hello"));
        il.add(new Child("World"));
        return il;
    }
}
```

But **what about the return type of `getItems()`?** It seems semantically wrong to me, since the result of the function *does* contain a `Parent` object which is *not a subclass* of `Parent` what I would expect from that method signature. Given this behaviour, I would have expected a simple `List<Parent>` as return type. However, since the compiler doesn’t complain, do I miss something? **Is there any benefit** from this implementation, aside from an (unnecessary) “write protection” for the result list? Or is this java style to write-protect result lists (not in this example, but, for example, to expose an object’s field list without needing to create a copy)? Or can this simply be considered “wrong” (in terms of teaching)? If so, why does neither the compiler nor even Eclipse complain about it, not even showing a hint?

Comment: I think you've listed the benefit - write protection. Whether it is required in your particular code example is another debate, but certainly neither the compiler nor Eclipse should warn you about anything.

Comment: I would see the benefit the other way around: read-guarantee. You know you can read to a `Parent`-typed variable. You don't know if the `List` is able to store `Parent` or only `Child` why it could be a bad idea to write to it.

Comment: In addition to the answers (which already cover the main point: Flexibility!) : 1. `Parent` **IS** a subclass of `Parent` and 2. The list is not "write protected": You can still add `null` (or remove elements)

Answer (score 4):

`List<A>` is invariant. `List<? extends A>` is covariant, and `List<? super A>` is contravariant.

The covariant type can't be modified without a cast (which makes sense, because mutable collections are inherently not covariant).

If the collection doesn't need to be modified, then there is no reason not to use `List<? extends A>` to gain the appropriate subtype relationships (e.g. `List<? extends Integer>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Number>`).

I wouldn't suggest looking at this as "write protection" since the cast to circumvent it is trivial. Look at it as simply using the most general type possible. If you're writing a method that accepts a `List<A>` argument, and that method never needs to modify the list, then `List<? extends A>` is the more general and thus more appropriate type.

As a return type, using covariance is also useful. Suppose you're implementing a method whose return type is `List<Number>`, and you have a `List<Integer>` you want to return. You're kinda found as a stranger in the Alps: Either copy it or do an ugly cast. But if your types were correct, and the interface called for a `List<? extends Number>`, then you could just return the thing you have.

Comment: `((List<Whatever>) list).add(whatever)`

Comment: If `Integer` is a subtype of `Number` that doesn't mean that `List<? extends Integer>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Number>`.

Comment: Yes - That's exactly what I said?

Comment: @ChrisMartin Ok, I thought that was what you meant. I'm not sure that's really trivial - its unchecked and brittle and requires knowledge of the actual type used.

Comment: Using the crappy standard collections library is already brittle and requires knowledge of the concrete type, since `List` is used for both mutable and immutable lists.

Answer (score 3):

You already mentioned the "write protection" as a benefit, which, depending on the usage scenario, may be useful or not.

Another benefit is *some* flexibility, in the sense that you can change the implementation of the method and write something along the lines of

```
    List<Child> il = new ArrayList<Child>();
    il.add(new Child("Hello"));
    il.add(new GrandChild("World")); // assume there is such a thing
    List<? extends Parent> result = il;
    return result;
```

which does change the type of the contents of your list, but it keeps the interface (read:public method signature) intact. This is crucial if you write a framework, for example.

Comment: It has to be `List<Child>` (otherwise you can't even add new elements), and then you can't add `GrandChild` instances. I upvoted this (accidentally, before I noticed this error), because it's IMHO the main reason: You can return a `List<Child>` which still counts as `List<? extends Parent>`.

Comment: My bad, started from the original code. Should be alright now.

Answer (score 2):

The `? extends X` and `? super Y` syntax comes in handy when you start working with specialized `List`s in sub-classes and you need to ensure that no invalid object is mixed in. With regular `ArrayList`s you can always risk an unchecked cast and circumvent the restriction, but maybe this example illustrates the way you can use the parametrizations:

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * http://stackoverflow.com/q/25617284/1266906
 */
public class ListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ParentList parents = new ParentList(new Parent("one"), new Child("two"));
        List<? extends Parent> parentsA = parents; // Read-Only, items assignable to Parent
        List<? super Parent> parentsB = parents; // Write-Only, input of type Parent
        List<Parent> parentC = parents; // Valid as A and B were valid
        List<? super Child> parentD = parents; // Valid as you can store a Child
        // List<? extends Child> parentE = parents; // Invalid as not all contained values are Child

        ChildList children = new ChildList(new Child("one"), new Child("two"));
        List<? extends Parent> childrenA = children; // Read-Only, items assignable to Parent
        // List<? super Parent> childrenB = children; // Invalid as ChildList can not store a Parent
        List<? super Child> childrenC = children; // Write-Only, input of type Child
        // List<Parent> childrenD = children; // Invalid as B was invalid
        List<Child> childrenE = children;
    }


    public static class ChildList extends AbstractList<Child> {

        private Child[] values;

        public ChildList(Child... values) {
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public Child get(int index) {
            return values[index];
        }

        @Override
        public Child set(int index, Child element) {
            Child oldValue = values[index];
            values[index] = element;
            return oldValue;
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return values.length;
        }
    }

    public static class ParentList extends AbstractList<Parent> {

        private Parent[] values;

        public ParentList(Parent... values) {
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public Parent get(int index) {
            return values[index];
        }

        @Override
        public Parent set(int index, Parent element) {
            Parent oldValue = values[index];
            values[index] = element;
            return oldValue;
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return values.length;
        }
    }

    public static class Parent {

        private final String value;

        public Parent(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }

    }

    public static class Child extends Parent {
        public Child(String value) {
            super(value);
        }
    }
}
```

### A last note on the naming:

- read `? extends X` either as '`X` or any type extending `X`' or 'something assignable to a variable of type `X`'
- read `? super X` either as '`X` or any type `X` extends' or 'something I can assign a variable of type `X` to'.

Comment: It's fine that you try to explain the workings of `? extends` and `? super`, but the lists will not be "read only". The lists can still be modified (they only can't be populated with wrong types)

Comment: @Marco13 without further casting you will not be able to call set. So practically it becomes read-only while technically it is not. There is `Collections.unmodifieableList()` to make it 'read-only' if you do not use reflection, ... or else: it becomes harder to write why I choose to call it read-only.

Comment: `list.set(0, null)` still works. But sure, in general, lists could/should be exposes as `Collections.unmodifiableList` - and in this case something like `List<Parent> p = Collections.unmodifiableList(childList)` works as well.

Comment: I would usally combine both like `List<? extends Parent> p = Collections.unmodifiableList(childList)` as then your compiler and your runtime will both say "read-only".

Answer (score -1):

when you say `List<? extends Parent>` it means any object of `Parent` Type or any of its children. I agree that the it is sort of misleading, but that's the way it works.

One potential benefit I can see from this pattern is when using reflection API in the `main` function.

Suppose if you have the function return `List<Parent>`, and in your `main()`, if you do

```
private static List<Parent> getItems() { ... }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<? extends Parent> items = getItems();
    for (Parent p : items) {
        System.out.println(p.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

would yield you

```
Parent
Parent
```

where as if you had

```
private static List<? extends Parent> getItems() { ... }
```

The main would print

```
Parent
Child
```

Comment: -1 This is not correct. It seemed odd to me, so I tested the code and it prints `Parent / Child` in both cases.

Comment: The instant you realize that generic typing is basically erased after compilation, you know that Java could not even do this if it wanted to...